# Selenium doesn't press Enter in sendKeys

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with keys sequences:

```
element.sendKeys(paramName,Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.ENTER);
```

In this sequences doesn't work `Keys.ENTER` and probably `Keys.ARROW_DOWN`.

I sent text to text field and than i need to get value from dropdown list. Value list in dropdown list appeared only after add text.

http://clip2net.com/s/3HT6zOA

Also, I tried:

```
element.sendKeys(paramName);
element.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Thanks a lot for  any help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to submit your input. So you can try to do the next:

1 After sending text try to skip the step with arrow down and press enter

```
element.sendKeys(paramName);
element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

OR if you need to select the item from the list you should find that element and click on it.

```
element.sendKeys(paramName);
WebElement elementToSelect = driver.findElement(By.selectorType("selector")).click();
element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

(How properly select an item from the dropdown depend on how this dropdown is implemented).

Comment: >>1 After sending text try to skip the step with arrow down and press enter. 

It's didn't work, because you need to press those what appears after 

element.sendKeys(paramName);

The second variant didn,t work too. I cant inspect the element in dropdown list, because it disappears after click on it.

Comment: Such variant work correctly.
element.sendKeys(paramName);
Thread.sleep(3000)
element.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);